# Node is not running, Nitrogen

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, nitrogen

In shell I typed `bin/dev page foo` and shell returned `Node is not running`, I checked my logs and noticed the message `epmd: epmd: node name already occupied nitrogen`

Then, in shell I typed `epmd -names` and it returned

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name nitrogen at port 61109
```

Running `epmd -debug` gives

```
epmd: Thu Jun 27 01:01:52 2013: epmd running - daemon = 0
epmd: Thu Jun 27 01:01:52 2013: there is already a epmd running at port 4369
```

I cannot stop the node, and when I try apparently it is active in the db

```
epmd: local epmd responded with <>
Killing not allowed - living nodes in database.
```

In Eshell, I received the following

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 27-Jun-2013::00:49:53 ===
** Connection attempt from disallowed node 'nitrogen_maint_19141@127.0.0.1' **
```

Is there a method to get Eshell to recognize this node, in order to run `bin/dev function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed you posting on the [Nitrogen mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nitrogenweb/RCifv5KXpkw/0WfPez_GYFUJ), and as I understand it, you've got it straightened out, but in this situation, I'd kill the running node manually with a `ps aux | grep nitrogen`, then kill the process it finds with a simple `kill XYZ`.

That, or, I've seen the "Node is not running" thing pop up when the process was launched with a different user, such that you don't have access to the erlang pipe.

Admittedly, my advice isn't terribly scientific (killing a process is pretty nasty), but it's a simple solution if for whatever reason something got hosed during launching and you're unable to attach to the node.

Comment: Thank you @chops! I tried the above, and it didn't result in attaching the node. The grep appears to show a normal process: `840   0.0  0.0  2434892    548 s001  S+   12:11PM   0:00.00 grep nitrogen` and a dangling one? `859   0.0  0.0  2435452    204   ??  S    12:14PM   0:00.00 epmd -daemon`, and I am unable to stop the normal process, however, I can stop the daemon, relaunch it, etc.

Comment: epmd is designed to stay running even after the process ends, and the first one in your list is actually the grep command itself that it's finding. With the node apparently not running, are you able to launch a nitrogen instance (`bin/nitrogen console`) and then use the `bin/dev` command? Keep in mind, `dev` will only function if the node is running.

Comment: sorry for the delay @chops. after launching nitrogen with `bin/nitrogen console`, I received the error `=ERROR REPORT==== 1-Jul-2013::00:29:45 ===
** Connection attempt from disallowed node 'nitrogen_maint_697@127.0.0.1' ** `. While the `epmd -names` command yields `epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name nitrogen at port 52185`

Comment: saweet!! i deleted my folder (i could not work my through that-- definitely had gotten myself in a loop). again, console would not run, grep'd the id, killed the process (not the daemon).. money!! I love this framework!!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it!